# множественное условие в тернарном операторе

Tags: javascript, switch

есть такой код где сравниваю строку:

```
search === 'name1'
            ? items[0].title
            : items[1].title
```

вопрос как передалать, так чтобы сравнивать много условий, и было больше вариантов выбора?
т.е. если name1 , то items[0].title , если name2 , то items[1].title , если name3 , то items[2].title и так далее..

Comment: ТОЛЬКО НЕ ТАК, ПОЖАЛУЙСТА! Этот код будет работать настолько медленно, насколько возможно, лучше используйте `switch case`)) А ещё можно сделать словарик, с помощью `new Map()`, если `switch case` покажется громоздким

Comment: Согласен с @EzioMercer.. Делать так можно, если это принятый стиль написания в команде разработчиков, того требует договоренность и проект уже имеет такие куски кода, в противном случае, избегать.. А так за `:` ставиться следующее условие например `10 > 15  ? 'ok' :  15 > 10 ? 'yes' :  'none';`

Comment: @Rudi 1. "принятый стиль написания в команде" - валить из такой команды как можно скорее. 2. "того требует договоренность" - валить из такой компании как можно быстрее. 3. "проект уже имеет такие куски кода" - брать и переписывать. Это всё что могу посоветовать в такой случае 

Comment: @EzioMercer Согласен, но бывают же странности разные всякие) "Макароны на скатерти" требуют поддержки, а проект несёт бабло.. Так и живём.. Сам не встречался с таким, но вселенная-то бесконечная))